# Where do I see the pin functions?

Tags: pinout, breakout, adafruit

I got this usb² to i²C board: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2264

and I wonder where I can see any information about what the pins D0-D7 or C0-C9 mean, actually also even the same about GND and 3V, 5V. Is the latter for supply in or out (or is it the same?)
The page refers to the chip ( https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/DS_FT232H.pdf ) but I don't think I can match the chip pins to the board pins. At least there are way more pins than available on the board.
At least on this image:

[image: img]

one can see some functionalities. Finally I am interested in voltage supply, GND and SDA/SCL. Do I see it correctly that there are two pins for SDA?

Then, just to understand this, what are C0-C9 ?

Answer (score 0):

You link to a page for shopping products. It's intended for purchasing items.

The shop page has a link to product page which describes how to use the product.

Please read the documentation on product page. It describes the pin functions. If that's not enough, you can always read the schematics how it connects to the IC, and read the datasheet and documentation of the IC, because basically, all that the Adafruit board is, is just a simple breakout board for the FT232H - which apparently is also the name for the Adafruit product.